# How to best play this Los Lonely Boys run?

Tags: guitar, fingering, picking

I'm trying to perfect the run at the end of the solo of "Heaven" by Los Lonely Boys which occurs at about 2:13.

I *think* this is how the left hand is played:

```
E|-----------------------------------------------------------------
B|-12-11----11-----------------------------------------------------
G|-------13----13-11-13-11----11-----------------------------------
D|-------------------------13----13-11-13-11----11-----------------
A|-------------------------------------------13----13-11-11-9----9-
E|------------------------------------------------------------11---
```

I'm not so sure how to play the right hand (picking) part.

Is he using alternate picking for every note, or are there pull-offs involved?

Could economy picking be used to optimize it?

Would it be easier if played in a different position?

Comment: When I play fast scale runs, I plan to pick it all and I try to pick it, and my left hand technique is such that if I miss a note then a pull-off will almost always happen and cover up my right hand miss. So my answer to "picking or pull-offs" would be "Yes!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like they are all 16th notes, here's a tab with the pull offs added in. Hope this helps!
[image: Los Lonely Boys Run]

Here is the alternative position:

[image]